# Manually sorting features in ArcGIS according to field other than what is being symbolized?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, legend

I have a hexagon grid with the dominant species of tree listed in each cell. I want to symbolize the tree type but put them in order of percentage of dominance in the legend. So a table like this:

*Maple - 85%

Oak  - 100%

Pine - 75%*

would end up looking like this in the legend:

*Oak  - 100%

Maple - 85%

Pine - 75%*

despite being out of alphabetical order.

Comment: A few questions for clarification...Are you using ArcPy or anything to create the legend? It also may be helpful to see a screenshot of what you are trying to accomplish,

Comment: no, it's just ArcGIS. The workaround is to manually rename the categories in the symbology window but I there's gotta be another way to do this. Every time I change the color ramp I'm gonna lose my classification titles.

Comment: It sounds like we need some more information like MaryBeth said above.  A screenshot would help.

Comment: You said, "table like this:", but your example is a line, not a table.  You need to clarify what you mean.  Explain where these values are coming from, how they're stored in the GDB and how the legend is constructed.

Comment: @SonofaBeach that's due to Stack Exchange formatting putting everything on the same line.  I have fixed the formatting

Comment: you referred to your data as a hexagon "grid" - assuming this is vector data, you can just reorder the categories in the symbology tab, which will result in the reorder in the legend.

Answer (score 2):

You wouldn't be able to do this using ArcMap built-in tools. However, this can be easily done using `arcpy` and Python scripting techniques. We are essentially interested in updating the layer labels for the symbology (unique values type).

1. Create a layer in the map document.

This is how attribute table would look like:

[image]

2. Choose Symbology > Unique values. Your tree species will be sorted alphabetically.

[image]

3. Run this snippet code in your Python window in ArcMap.

Code when both tree type and percentage are stored in multiple fields:

```
import arcpy.mapping as mp

mxd = mp.MapDocument('current')
lyr = mp.ListLayers(mxd, 'TreeTypes')[0]
symb = lyr.symbology

symb.classLabels
print(symb.classLabels)
#[u'Apple', u'Birch', u'Cedar', u'Maple', u'Oak', u'Pear', u'Poplar', u'Willow']
lookup = {f[0]: int(f[1]) for f in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr,["TreeType","Percentage"])}
print(lookup)
#{u'Apple': 20, u'Willow': 75, u'Pear': 30, u'Oak': 100, u'Poplar': 40, u'Birch': 50, u'Cedar': 10, u'Maple': 80}

symb.classLabels = sorted(symb.classLabels, key=lookup.get, reverse=True)
symb.classLabels = [i + ' - ' + str(lookup[i]) + '%' for i in symb.classLabels]
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

4. Your layer symbology will be updated. You can create a new legend now which will use the labels you want. Should you already have a legend created, you can run `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` in Python window to refresh it.

[image]

Note: the code above assumes that you have your percentage values stored in a field named Percentage. Should you keep both the tree type and percentage in a single field (not the best alternative in terms of data management), then you should run this code instead:

Code when both tree type and percentage are stored in a single field:

```
import arcpy.mapping as mp

mxd = mp.MapDocument('current')
lyr = mp.ListLayers(mxd, 'TreeTypes')[0]
symb = lyr.symbology

symb.classLabels
print(symb.classLabels)
#[u'Apple - 20%', u'Birch - 50%', u'Cedar - 10%', u'Maple - 80%', u'Oak - 100%', u'Pear - 30%', u'Poplar - 40%', u'Willow - 75%']

symb.classLabels = sorted(symb.classLabels, key=lambda x: int(x.split(' - ')[1].split('%')[0]), reverse=True)
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: question regarding a code function in the top script. "reverse = True"  is this arranging the classes from greatest to least?

Comment: @Joe, this is correct. The ones with the largest percentage value will end up in the top of the list. You can think of `reverse=True` as SQL `DESC` that is in descending order.

Comment: so it is safe to say that by default its ascending order?

Comment: @Joe this is correct. By default the integers will be sorted in ascending order, so you can leave out the `reverse` parameter. I've used the reverse order because the questioner was interested in descending order.

Comment: @cpbride, have you managed to execute the Python code? Has it solved your problem?